# Conjugation of a subgrpoup of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the situation $K\trianglelefteq H<G$ of a group $G$ and subgroups $K$ and $H$, where $K$ is normal in $H$. If $K$ is a maximal subgroup of $H$.

Now for any $g\in G$. Is $gKg^{-1}$ a subgroup of $H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always. The elbow room comes from $H$ not being a normal subgroup of $G$. The smallest counterexample that occured to me is the following.

Let $G=S_4$. Let $K$ be the subgroup generated by $r=(1234)$, and $H$ be the subgroup generated by $r$ and $s=(13)$. Then $H$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order eight. The only order four elements of $H$ are thus $r^{\pm1}$. But, when $g=(23)\in S_4$ we have $grg^{-1}=(1324)\notin H$.

Comment: I think we can also find a counterexample inside $G=D_6=\langle (123456), (25)(34)\rangle$. Let $H=\langle (25)(34),(14)(23)(56)\rangle$ be the group generated by two (commuting) reflections w.r.t. orthogonal lines. Not all $G$ conjugates of $(25)(34)$ will be elements of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Let H be any group with a normal non-trivial subgroup $K$ and let $G=H*L$ be the free product of H and any non-trivial group $L$.

Comment: This is probably the worst way in which what you want can fail.

Answer (score 1):

To analyze this configuration a bit further: suppose that indeed we have $gKg^{-1} \subseteq H$ for all $g \in G$. Then, $K \subseteq \bigcap_{g \in G}gHg^{-1}=core_G(H)$, the largest normal subgroup of $G$, contained in $H$. Since $K$ is maximal in $H$, it follows that $K=core_G(H)$ or $H=core_G(H)$. The latter is equivalent to $H$ being normal in $G$.